# idle won't start on macOS 11.7, python 3.12. says macOS 11 (1107) or later required, have instead 11 (1106)

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

The title says it: I did `pip install idle`, after upgrading `pip`. Now I get this:

```
 % idle
macOS 11 (1107) or later required, have instead 11 (1106) !
zsh: abort      idle
```

My Mac About says: BigSur 11.7

Hardware Overview:

```
  Model Name:   MacBook Air
  Model Identifier: MacBookAir10,1
  Chip: Apple M1
  Total Number of Cores:    8 (4 performance and 4 efficiency)
  Memory:   8 GB
  System Firmware Version:  7459.141.1
  OS Loader Version:    6723.140.2
  Serial Number (system):   FVHFGTB1Q6L4
  Hardware UUID:    652F22EB-2C8E-5989-84D9-81DF25094463
  Provisioning UDID:    00008103-001870E00131001E
  Activation Lock Status:   Disabled
```

Tried installing & starting idle.

Comment: Neither of [the prepackaged IDLE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html) nor [the library you installed](https://pypi.org/project/idle/) provides an `idle` executable. Whatever you are running, it's not what you just installed.

Comment: Python's IDLE is installed with Python itself.  Go to Launcher to find it.

Comment: I run python and IDLE on Catalina (10.6 as I remember).

Answer (score -3):

I would try to uninstall and then again install the program as this helped me in most of the cases. Also i would save my codes on some outer device as they, if they are in python file, might disappear.

Also you can try using python command prompt (never actually tried this) and manually install/reinstall it. You can also use it to check if it's ok and installed where it should be.

Try this but **I don't work with mac** so I can't help you more if it wont help.

Comment: Honestly, if you don't know that your answer is correct, then don't post it.  You should delete this before you collect negative votes.